# jquery dialog close function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

i want when click on close (X) button on dialog do some javascript function .
i test some code but no work for me .
do like this

```
$(#dialog).close 
{
function one();
function two();
...
}
```

tset this and not work :

```
<script>

  function beh()
  {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
    beforeClose: function(event, ui) {
      alert('hi');
   },
    width: 660,
    height: 495,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    hide: "fadeout",
    resizable: false,
    }
    );
  });
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: there's no need to put `$(document).ready()` _inside_ another function - not least because if you never call that function then the handler will never got called either.

Comment: so how i can call dialog when click ab button? i should remove  $(document).ready(function() line?

Comment: no, _everything_ should be inside a `$(document).ready()` function, unless there's a good reason not to.  But that function should only register the button click handler, which will then call _another_ function to show the dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should attach a callback to the [`beforeclose`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-beforeClose) event like so:

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
   beforeClose: function(event, ui) {
       //call functions 
       customfunction1();
       customfunction2();
   }
});
```

then when you [close](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#method-close) the dialog, it should fire:

```
$('#dialog').dialog('close');
```

Comment: @behzadn you missed a `,` after the event

Comment: can you insert correct code here? i insert , after event but not work yet